# Algebraic proof that $\det AB = \det A \cdot \det B$ using Leibniz formula for determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, permutations, determinant, products

The [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) allows us to express an $n \times n$ matrix determinant as a sum over permutations in $S_n$:

$$\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \prod_{k=1}^n a_{\sigma(k), k}$$

A surprising amount of properties about determinants can be proven from *this formula alone*, using algebraic manipulation and basic facts about permutations. (Particularly, it's simple (and fun) to use it to show what happens to the determinant of a matrix when you apply elementary row operations; try it!)

Is there an existing proof of the fact that $\det AB = \det A \cdot \det B$ for $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, relying only on algebraic manipulation of the above formula? The resulting sums get rather ugly:

\begin{align*}
\det A \cdot \det B &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_n, \tau \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma \circ \tau) \prod_{k=1}^n
a_{\sigma(k), k} \cdot b_{\tau(k), k} \\ &\stackrel{\color{red}?}{\color{red}=} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{k=1}^n \left( \sum_{x=1}^n
a_{\sigma(k), x} \cdot b_{x, k} \right) \\&= \det AB
\end{align*}

How would I go about trying to prove that these expressions are equivalent?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177560/proving-determinant-product-rule-combinatorially.

Comment: Uggh.  So much more difficult than the [geometric algebra approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195010/question-on-linear-algebra-determinant-multiplication/1195058#1195058). 